# new MongoId() - Is it a write operation or read operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongodb with php. I want to know when we create a new mongo id using **new MongoId()** How does it consult to the database for ensuring unique id, I mean is it a write operation or read operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generation of the ObjectId happens locally, it's not a database operation. 4 values are used to generate the ObjectId:

- Time: `::Time.new.to_i`
- Machine ID: `Digest::MD5.digest(Socket.gethostname).unpack("N")[0]`
- Process ID: `Process.pid % 0xFFFF`
- Counter: `@counter = (@counter + 1) % 0xFFFFFF`

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/master/lib/bson/object_id.rb#L310-L394).